# cannot check in; \packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\EntityFramework.6.1.3.nupkg: The server returned content type text/plain, which is not supported

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to check in my code, but I keep getting this error;

```
\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\EntityFramework.6.1.3.nupkg: 
The server returned content type text/plain, which is not supported.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was that there was a setting on Sophos that excluded this file. When that was fixed, then no problem.

Comment: How did you fix in Sophos

Comment: I had a colleague who sorted out Sophos for me. I can't remember how.